# Adding Token to Uniswap

Tags: solidity, uniswap, mainnet

I was just wondering, how would I get my token (lets say abcToken) to both, pair with ETH -> abcToken/ETH, & implement a swapping function for abcToken/ETH on Uniswap?

Will I need to implement this code in my own smart contracts or can I create this with the Uniswap functions when I deploy abcToken?

Answer (score 0):

No, you just go to the add liquidity function on uniswap. You then choose the price of your token and deposit the ETH.